# Parallel or simultaneous computation of the function after pressing the button

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, parallel-processing

In my code, after the button is pressed the method is called where there are calls to three functions with calculations and export to PDF file. One of the functions takes a field of the class as a parameter which is changed by moving a slider in the app. The problem is that the animation of pressing the button lags due to the calculations and export. Also, the CPU usage of the exe jumps up by 7% - 15%.

The method does not return anything and the result of its work is just PDF file, so I don't need to wait until it finishes but just start it and care about other events.

I want to make the method compute in parallel or simultaneously, so it does not slow down the whole app and animation of pressing the button plays smoothly.

**Attempts**

I have tried to change the function type to Future and add async, but it didn't help.

I have also tried to use `Isolate.run`. It works if I put only two functions inside of that, but if I add the third one which takes the field of the class as a parameter it stops working.

Here is the simplified look of the class and the method which is invoked after the button is pressed.

```js
class Pattern{
    int scale = 10; //it's changed by slider

    void exportImage() {
        
        ImageBMP image = drawPattern(scale); //if I add this to Isolate it breakes
        
        var dividedImage = divideImage(image);
        
        createPDF(dividedImage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it by using `Isolate.run` and creating local variable for `scale` in the method.

The final code looks something like that

```
import 'dart:isolate';

class Pattern{
    int scale = 10; //it's changed by slider

    void exportImage() {
    
        int l_scale = scale;
        
        Isolate.run
        (()
            {
              ImageBMP image = drawPattern(l_scale); 
              var dividedImage = divideImage(image);
              createPDF(dividedImage);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

If someone can benefit from it:

Same way can be used for methods. The method `drawPattern` in my code is different for every child of the `Pattern` class, but takes the same argument `int scale` and for quite long I couldn't put it in Isolate because it takes only static functions. The solution for that was to create a field in the `Pattern` class which would store the function and then in `exportImage` function create local variable similarly to what I did with `scale`. So finally my code looks like that

```
import 'dart:isolate';

class Pattern{
    int scale = 10; //it's changed by slider
    late ImageBMP Function(int) drawPattern;

    void exportImage() {
    
        int l_scale = scale;
        ImageBMP Function(int) l_drawPattern = drawPattern;
        
        Isolate.run
        (()
            {
              ImageBMP image = l_drawPattern(l_scale); 
              var dividedImage = divideImage(image);
              createPDF(dividedImage);
            }
        );
    }
}

//example of child class
class Square extends Pattern{
  Square() {
    drawPattern = drawSquare;
  }
}
//drawSquare is a top-level function which takes 'int scale' as argument
```

Answer (score 0):

Import foundation.dart which has the compute method :

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
```

Then use compute within your exportImage method to do its work in the background.

```
void exportImage() {
  compute((_) {
    ImageBMP image = createImage();
    var dividedImage = divideImage(image);
    createPDF(dividedImage);
  }, null);
}
```

Comment: You should also provide code which is solving the OP's problem using the compute function or an example of compute function.

Comment: If I understand correctly, `compute` runs an Isolate. I have tried that and it worked to some extent but not enough. I updated my question so you can see what exectly I have tried and added more details about the problem.